# Find parent keys in hierarchy in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I have below `Array` structure for `$array`.

```
Array
  (
       [WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE] => Array
       (
        [TITLE] => Widget Builder
        [WIDGET_TYPE_LBL] => Select Widget Type
        [RANGE_LBL] => Select Range
        [RANGE_TYPE_LBL] => Select Range Type
        [TOP_SERVICE_CHKBOX] => Top Services
        [SR_STATE_LBL] => Select Sr States
        [SR_TYPE_LBL] => Select Sr Types
        [SR_CATEGORY_LBL] => Select Sr Categories
        [SR_SOURCE_LBL] => Select Sources
        [SR_PROVIDER_LBL] => Select Sr Provider
        [ADDRESS] => Enter Address
        [SUBMIT_BTN] => Generate Data
        [CHART_DIV] => Array
            (
                [TYPE] => Select chart type
                [SAVE_BTN] => Save Widget
                [SERIES_NAME] => Change Parameters
                [PARA_DIALOG] => Array
                    (
                        [TITLE] => Chart Parameters
                        [SERIESNAME] => Series Name
                        [YAXISNAME] => Y axies name
                        [VALIDATION] => Array
                            (
                                [SERIESNAME] => Please enter series name
                                [YAXISNAME] => Please enter y axis name
                            )

                        [SAVE_BTN] => Save
                        [CANCEL_BTN] => Cancel
                    )

                [SAVE_DIALOG] => Array
                    (
                        [TITLE] => Save Chart
                        [CHART_NAME] => Chart Name
                        [SHOW_TO_USER] => System Widget
                        [VALIDATION] => Array
                            (
                                [CHART_NAME] => Please enter chart name
                            )

                        [SAVE_BTN] => Save
                        [CANCEL_BTN] => Cancel
                    )

            )

        [GRID_DIV] => Array
            (
            )

    )

  )
```

**Problem:**

I want to build a function in PHP like if I enter a value,then it should return all parent keys in hierarchy.

Let's say for example if I enter `Please enter y axis name`,it should return as

```
$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']['CHART_DIV']['PARA_DIALOG']['VALIDATION']['YAXISNAME'];
```

**Edit:** I tried like [How to get hierarchy path of an element in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544988/how-to-get-hierarchy-path-of-an-element-in-an-array) but it returns as a string but I want as array key indexed. That means

```
print_r($array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']['CHART_DIV']['PARA_DIALOG']['VALIDATION']['YAXISNAME']);

//returns Please enter y axis name
```

I am using PHP 5.5.9

Comment: I don't understand. The function should return the same value you entered? In your sample, `$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']...` will actually return the string `"Please enter y axis name"`

Comment: I think the poster wants the function to return the array path that contains the string rather than the value.

Comment: What if the same text occurs twice in the array?

Comment: @Daan , it is possible but will be inside different keys

Comment: Which path do you want to get in return then? Both?

Comment: Then it should return both which will be in array itself.

Comment: Recursion, string concat and explode back .. I will have to write a solution for that..that's the hint though..

Comment: yeah right,but `array` is kinda big though.

Comment: @RyanVincent ,do I need to add any `external library`,where does `walktree`come from? I prefer it in core `php` way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you are feeling like you could use a *quick & dirty* approach, you may want to try the `function` below which uses nested `foreach` Loops. But then, if you are feeling geeky, you could simply refactor the nested loops on your own and turn them into a shorter recursive algorithm. To test this *Quick & Dirty* method, go [here](https://eval.in/620473):

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
<?php

    $array = [
        'WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE' => [
            "TITLE"                 => "Widget Builder",
            "WIDGET_TYPE_LBL"       => "Select Widget Type",
            "RANGE_LBL"             => "Select Range",
            "RANGE_TYPE_LBL"        => "Select Range Type",
            "TOP_SERVICE_CHKBOX"    => "Top Services",
            "SR_STATE_LBL"          => "Select Sr States",
            "SR_TYPE_LBL"           => "Select Sr Types",
            "SR_CATEGORY_LBL"       => "Select Sr Categories",
            "SR_SOURCE_LBL"         => "Select Sources",
            "SR_PROVIDER_LBL"       => "Select Sr Provider",
            "ADDRESS"               => "Enter Address",
            "SUBMIT_BTN"            => "Generate Data",
            "CHART_DIV"             => [
                "TYPE"          => "Select chart type",
                "SAVE_BTN"      => "Save Widget",
                "SERIES_NAME"   => "Change Parameters",
                "PARA_DIALOG"   => [
                    "TITLE"         => "Chart Parameters",
                    "SERIESNAME"    => "Series Name",
                    "YAXISNAME"     => "Y axies name",
                    "VALIDATION"    => [
                        "SERIESNAME"    => "Please enter series name",
                        "YAXISNAME"     => "Please enter y axis name",

                    ],
                    "SAVE_BTN"          => "Save",
                    "CANCEL_BTN"        => "Cancel",
                ],
                "SAVE_DIALOG"   =>[
                    "TITLE"         => "Save Chart",
                    "CHART_NAME"    => "Chart Name",
                    "SHOW_TO_USER"  => "System Widget",
                    "VALIDATION"    => [
                        "CHART_NAME"    => "Please enter chart name",
                    ],
                    "SAVE_BTN"      => "Save",
                    "CANCEL_BTN"    => "Cancel",
                ],

            ],
            "GRID_DIV"              => [],
        ],
    ];
```

**QUICK & DIRTY FUNCTION:**

```
<?php

    function keywordLookUp(array $array, $keyWord, $arrayName="\$array"){
        $route   = $mainKey   = null; $arrRte   = $arrResult   = [];
        foreach($array as $intKey=>$item){
            $mainKey =  $route = "{$arrayName}['{$intKey}']";
            if(is_array($item)){
                foreach($item as $iKey=>$innerItem){
                    if($lKey = array_search($keyWord, $item)){
                        $route .=  $s = "['$lKey']"; break;
                    }
                    if(is_array($innerItem)){
                        foreach($innerItem as $iKey2=>$innerItem2){
                            if($lKey = array_search($keyWord, $innerItem)){
                                if(isset($s)){
                                if(! array_search($route, $arrRte)){$arrRte[] = $route;}
                                    $arrRte[] =  "{$s}['$lKey']";
                                    $route .=  "\n{$s}['$lKey']";
                                }else{
                                    $route .=  "['$iKey']['$lKey']";
                                }   $s      =  str_replace("['$lKey']", "", $route); break;
                            }
                            if(is_array($innerItem2)){
                                foreach($innerItem2 as $iKey3=>$innerItem3){
                                    if($lKey = array_search($keyWord, $innerItem2)){
                                        if(isset($s)){
                                            if(! array_search($route, $arrRte)){$arrRte[] = $route;}
                                            $arrRte[] ="{$s}['$iKey2']['$lKey']";
                                            $route .=  "\n{$s}['$iKey2']['$lKey']";
                                        }else{
                                            $route .=  "['$iKey']['$iKey2']['$lKey']";
                                        }   $s      =  str_replace("['$iKey2']['$lKey']", "", $route); break;
                                    }
                                    if(is_array($innerItem3)){
                                        foreach($innerItem3 as $iKey4=>$innerItem4){
                                            if($lKey = array_search($keyWord, $innerItem3)){
                                                if(isset($s)){
                                                    if(! array_search($route, $arrRte)){$arrRte[] = $route;}
                                                    $arrRte[] = "{$s}['$iKey3']['$lKey']";
                                                    $route .=  "\n{$s}['$iKey3']['$lKey']";
                                                }else{
                                                    $route .=  "['$iKey']['$iKey2']['$iKey3']['$lKey']";
                                                }break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $fin = ($route == $mainKey) ? null : $route;
        $fin = (!empty($arrRte) && sizeof($arrRte > 1))?$arrRte:$fin;
        return $fin;
    }

    $path  = keywordLookUp($array, "Please enter y axis name");
    $path2 = keywordLookUp($array, "Chart Parameters");
    $path3 = keywordLookUp($array, "Cancel");

    var_dump($path);
    // PRODUCES::  string '$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']['CHART_DIV']['PARA_DIALOG']['VALIDATION']['SERIESNAME']' (length=87)

    var_dump($path2);
    // PRODUCES::  string '$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']['CHART_DIV']['PARA_DIALOG']['TITLE']' (length=68)

    var_dump($path3);
    // PRODUCES:: 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']['CHART_DIV']['PARA_DIALOG']['CANCEL_BTN']' (length=73)
      1 => string '$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']['CHART_DIV']['SAVE_DIALOG']['CANCEL_BTN']' (length=73)
```

Comment: The solution doesn't include the top-level key. It also doesn't support deeply nested arrays since you hard-code the depth.  Finally, OP said that if there are multiple matching paths, the function should return an array of all such paths, which this doesn't do.  it's an interesting approach though.

Comment: @ BeetleJuice   Thanks a lot for pointing that out but i think you should also have taken notice of the points: ***Quick & Dirty*** and  ***if you are feeling geeky, you could simply refactor the nested loops on your own and turn them into a shorter recursive algorithm***. And yes, it does not support deeply nested structure and that was why i mentioned, the recursive algorithm which the OP was asked to implement.... yet, thanks...

Comment: @Hiranya   Sure... the Post has just been updated to include that... it's advised that you consider implementing a recursive algorithm if your array goes deeper than 4 Levels....

Comment: @Poiz  I did read your post. I decided to comment because even as a quick & dirty solution it didn't return the right answer because of the other reasons I pointed out. The depth isn't a big deal really relative to the other reasons. I didn't mean to offend (sorry if I did).

Comment: @ BeetleJuice    One only gets offended when what was said contains no Truth.... If you are clearly right in your point, why should one be offended? Perhaps, the writing tone didn't come out right but honestly, No offence taken or even felt.... and as already confirmed; you were right... ;-)

Comment: @Hiranya Nice Observation but also fixed here: https://eval.in/620464 ... as well as the Post here ;-)

Comment: Sure,I was trying to fix your code as I got two `Cancel` values which is currently getting from `PARA_DIALOG` but not from `SAVE_DIALOG`, I am trying to receive them in `array`

Comment: What should be done to make it dynamic  `$route      = "\$array['WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE']";` I mean to get the top `key`

Comment: @Hiranya    The Post was updated... the `top Key` now comes dynamically from the `foreach` Loop and is not fed manually. However, you may use the 3 Argument to give the name of the array like `$array` or `$data`... (just in case).... Cheers... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The function below searches `$source` array and returns an array with all matching paths for the `$target` value. If the value is not found in `$source`, it returns an empty array.

```
function pathFinder($target, array $source, $parentPath=''){
    $results=[];
    foreach($source as $k => $v){
        $path = $parentPath.'/'.$k; //current path
        //if element is array, recurse and import found results
        if(is_array($v) && $result=pathFinder($target, $v,$path)){
            foreach($result as $r) array_push($results,$r);
        }
        //else add element to results if it matches $target
        elseif($v===$target) $results[]=$path;     
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Usage:

```
$target = 'Please enter axis Y name';
$foundPaths = pathFinder($target, $array);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/ndPas)

Comment: it returns `/WIDGET_BUILDER_CREATE/CHART_DIV/PARA_DIALOG/VALIDATION/YAXISNAME`,but not as `array index`

Comment: @Hiranya So I did the hard part for you. Surely you can do the rest. Just work on the line `$path = $parentPath.'/'.$k;` to format the path as you wish. Or just format the path the function returns by doing `explode('/',$result)` and then adding brackets `[]` around each result.  If you choose to use my answer as the basis for your solution, don't forget to upvote and select it.